# how to import different methods from different files to another javascript file for page objects E2E testing using protractor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor, e2e-testing

how to import different methods from different files to another javascript file for page objects E2E testing using protractor.
like i am dividing the page-objects as per each individual page and writing the all possible actions on that page as methods.
so, how to import those methods from multiple pages(files) to my test file.

Answer (score 0):

You just use `require` to import your page objects into the specs:

```
var myPage = require("./po/mypage.po.js");
```

See examples at:

- [Using Page Objects to Overcome Protractor's Shortcomings](http://www.thoughtworks.com/insights/blog/using-page-objects-overcome-protractors-shortcomings)
- [Using Page Objects to Organize Tests](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/page-objects.md)